# Помогите избавиться от дубляжа кода

Tags: c#, unity3d

подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от дубляжа.

```
        private float GetXPositionForShapeSquare(ShapeData shapeData, int column, Vector2 moveDistance)
        {
            var shiftOnX = 0f;
            
            if (shapeData.columns > 1)
            {
                float startXPos;
                if (shapeData.columns % 2 != 0)
                    startXPos = (shapeData.columns / 2) * moveDistance.x * -1;
                else
                    startXPos = ((shapeData.columns / 2) - 1) * moveDistance.x * -1 - moveDistance.x / 2;
                shiftOnX = startXPos + column * moveDistance.x;
                return shiftOnX;
            }

            return shiftOnX;
        }

        private float GetYPositionForShapeSquare(ShapeData shapeData, int row, Vector2 moveDistance)
        {
            var shiftOnY = 0f;
            
            if (shapeData.rows > 1)
            {
                float startYPos;
                if (shapeData.rows % 2 != 0)
                    startYPos = (shapeData.rows / 2) * moveDistance.y;
                else
                    startYPos = ((shapeData.rows / 2) - 1) * moveDistance.y + moveDistance.y / 2;
                shiftOnY = startYPos - row * moveDistance.y;
            }
            return shiftOnY;
        }
```

Comment: сделайте метод, который будет возвращать точку, где будут и х, и y. Т.е. объедините эти 2 метода в один

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, можно обойтись простым рефакторингом:

```
private float GetPositionGeneric(int size, int pos, float distance)
{
    var shift = 0f;
    
    if (size > 1)
    {
        float start;
        if (size % 2 != 0)
            start = (size / 2) * distance;
        else
            start = ((size / 2) - 1) * distance + distance / 2;
        shift = start - pos * distance;
        return shift;
    }

    return shift;
}

private float GetXPositionForShapeSquare(ShapeData shapeData, int column, Vector2 moveDistance)
{
    return GetPositionGeneric(shapeData.columns, column, -moveDistance.x);
}

private float GetYPositionForShapeSquare(ShapeData shapeData, int row, Vector2 moveDistance)
{
    return GetPositionGeneric(shapeData.rows, row, moveDistance.y);
}
```

Ещё один рефакторинг для `GetPositionGeneric`. Избавимся от `start`:

```
...
if (size % 2 != 0) {
    shift = (size / 2) * distance - pos * distance;
} else {
    shift = ((size / 2) - 1) * distance + distance / 2 - pos * distance;
}
...
```

Вынесем `distance` за скобки:

```
...
if (size % 2 != 0) {
    shift = (size / 2 - pos) * distance;
} else {
    shift = (size / 2 - 0.5f - pos) * distance;
}
...
```

Заменим деление с целочисленного на вещественное:

```
...
if (size % 2 != 0) {
    shift = (size / 2.f - 0.5f - pos) * distance;
} else {
    shift = (size / 2.f - 0.5f - pos) * distance;
}
...
```

Уберём ненужный теперь `if`:

```
private float GetPositionGeneric(int size, int pos, float distance)
{
    if (size > 1)
    {
        return (size / 2.f - 0.5f - pos) * distance;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Не знаю нужен ли оставшийся `if`. Возможно его тоже следует убрать.